# Using preg_split to split with a delimiter OR every x characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

Hello ||||overflow crowd :)
I'm afraid I couldn't find an answer anywhere, so here goes:

My code:

```
$stuff = '00#00#e0#12#ff#a3#00#01#b0#23#91#00#00#e4#11#ff#a2#'; //not exact, just a random example
$output = preg_split('/(?:[a-f0-9#]{12}| ff# )/', $stuff);
```

My expectations:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 00#00#e0#12#
    [1] => a3#00#01#b0#
    [2] => 23#91#00#00#
    [3] => e4#11##
    [4] => a2#
)
```

Long story short, I'm trying to split on every occurance of ff# or every 12 characters if there's no delimiter in sight.
Alternative suggestions are welcome as well, just thought preg_split would be able to do that; I just suck at regex :(

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No regex needed. Try:

```
$result = array();
foreach (explode('ff#', $stuff) as $piece) {
    $result = array_merge($result, str_split($piece, 12));
}

print_r($result);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 00#00#e0#12#
    [1] => a3#00#01#b0#
    [2] => 23#91#00#00#
    [3] => e4#11#
    [4] => a2#
)
```

This came to mind when I tried to come up with a regex solution:

[image: square peg]

Answer (score 2):

Quick, off-the-cuff solution:

```
$regex_output = preg_split('/ff#/', $stuff);
$output = Array();
foreach ($regex_output as $string)
{
    while (strlen($string) > 12)
    {
        $output[] = substr($string, 0, 12);
        $string = substr($string, 12);
    }

    $output[] = $string;
}
```

I'm sure someone will come up with something much more elegant.

Comment: NUE's solutions looks smaller but this one works too as it seems, thanks for that :D